# My input box expands slightly when bold font is used. Not what I want to happen

Tags: input

This one's driving me up the wall. And after more than an hour's web searching, I am no closer to a solution than when I first began. Sounds like a song. Anyway, the input box that I have created for a Moodle quiz has a different colour when I do a hover or when in focus (inputting data). The nagging PROBLEM is that when I hover over the input box, OR when I enter data, the box expands slightly and pushes the text slightly to the left (or the right). Very unslightly. That's because I've programmed the CSS to display the text as bold on focus or on hover.

Here's my code:

```
input[type=text]
{
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
    color:#000;
    padding:0px 2px;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size: medium; font-family: 'century gothic', futura;
    font-weight:normal;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -webkit-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;
    -moz-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;
    -ms-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;
    -o-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s; transition:border linear             0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px
}

.que .formulation input[type=text]
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic',futura; padding:0px 2px;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.que .formulation input[type=text]:hover
{
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #FFFFA7;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic',futura; padding:0px 2px;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.que .formulation input[type=text]:focus
{
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#fff;
    background: #FFFFA7;
    border:1px solid #000; color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic',futura;
    padding:0px 2x;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

I've tried changing the padding values, but it only makes it worse.

What should I do? Pray do tell.

A poor starving programmer
Frankie Kam

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by giving your original input css class a numeric (literal or relative) font-size instead of medium.   It also helps to clean up the duplicate styles in your hover and focus styles if only helps with readability.  CSS's whole purpose is to cascade.  See cleaned up code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5dQR7/

```
input[type=text]
{
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
    color:#000;
    padding:0px 2px;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-family: 'century gothic', futura;
    font-weight:normal;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -webkit-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;
    -moz-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;
    -ms-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;
    -o-transition:border linear 0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s; transition:border linear             0.2s,box-shadow linear 0.2s;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px;

}

.que .formulation input[type=text]
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic',futura; 
    padding:0px 2px;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.que .formulation input[type=text]:hover
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #FFFFA7;
}

.que .formulation input[type=text]:focus
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #FFFFA7;
}
```

Comment: Thanks big Jake. You mean to my CSS? Unfortunately it didn't have an effect. I am using Chrome.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle out for the latest I wrote above.  I just tested it in chrome and it works.

Comment: Hi Jake. Thanks for refactoring my messy code. I tried your fiddle. Is it just me, or does the input box still slightly expand when I do a mouseover it? I am using Chrome 31.0.1650.57m.